# Get all Images from a Folder and add it to Slider

Tags: android, slider, android-image

I have a folder named first - `res/drawable/pics/first`.The folder can contain upto 5 images(5 or less than 5).I need to loop through all these images and add to this slider https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Is something like this possible?

```
     x=5;
     sliderShow1 = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad1); 
     TextSliderView[] textSliderViewarray=new  TextSliderView[x];
     for (int y=0;y<x;y++)
     {
         textSliderViewarray[y]=new  TextSliderView(this);
     }

     for (int y=0;y<x;y++)
     {

         textSliderViewarray[y].description(" ").image("@drawable/pics/first/"+Integer.toString(y+1)+".png");
         sliderShow1.addSlider(textSliderViewarray[y]);
     }
```

This code creates 5 sliders with blank content.

Comment: juz try to run it urself... if u get any error, add the error with this question... One more thing, while using @drawable u dnt need to use the file extension.. so i would suggest u to remove ".png" part...

Comment: @RishadAppat See my update.

Comment: u removed ".png" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The root folder of the images should be drawable. Don't keep in nested folders.

Use the following code:

```
for (int y=0;y<x;y++)
{
    // Assuming image names as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png ...
    String resourceName = Integer.toString(y); // Extension is not needed.
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    textSliderViewarray[y].description(" ").image(resourceId);
    sliderShow1.addSlider(textSliderViewarray[y]);
}
```